# Simple Abstract class concept

Tags: php, oop

I am a bit new to PHP OOP so I need you guys help here. I am trying to understand when to use abstract function inside abstract class.

for example

```
abstract class User{
    abstract function login();
    //how do I decide if I should make login function as abstract or regular function.              
    abstract function permission();

    function AccountCredit (){
       echo 'show account credits';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An abstract class is a class that doesn't ever make sense to actually create (instantiate), like if your classes were "Beagle" and "Terrier", a "Dog" doesn't really make sense.

Color and hairtype would only apply to "Beagle" and "Terrier" but not "Dog", right? So it would be abstract at the Dog level.

Any method that only applied to a single breed would just not exist in "Dog" at all.

numberOfLegs would have an implementation at "Dog" level (not abstract) and the children could just inherit it (by not saying anything about it).

Note that if you were instantiating actual dogs, the breeds will become abstract--also if you were instantiating actual dogs they might need to overried numberOfLegs to account for individual dogs that have had accidents.

If you are new to OO, however, may I make a suggestion?  Keep all inheritence to a minimum, only do it when you are really forced to.  It seems that when a good programmer "Gets" OO their first thought is to link everything into one giant object tree--this turns out not to work very well.  You are better off using encapsulation instead of extending nearly every time.

Answer (score 1):

You make a method abstract if there's no sensible default behavior that *all* subclasses can use if they choose or override if they wish.

Answer (score 1):

When You define abstract function within a class (that must be declared abstract then, too), it means that this function must be implemented within the classes extending this abstract class.

You may define abstract function if the functionality will very differ or depend on the class extending the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Is the login function going to be the same for all Users? If so, then it should be implemented as low down as possible (in this abstract class).

If there are going to be multiple types of User, each needing different login functions, then leave it abstract and implement it differently in each implementing superclass to the needs of each type of User.

Answer (score 0):

A abstract class is a contract between the abstract class and all classes that inherit from abstract class.

The diference between abstract class and an interface is that the interface don't implements any method, only the signatures of the methods.

When you inherit from a abstract class, you must implement  all abstract methods. All the rest of not abstract methods, you will inherit it, the rest you extends how in a normal class